Strange memory/IO errors when building nextjs/node app inside docker
I have Linux server with 1.3T of nvme ssd, and 64gb of ram memory.
There is production app based on latest nextjs and nod. So I have docker-compose with container for the frontend where I just copy src files and perform in Dockerfile:
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

Everything worked fine for some time, but yesterday I encountered different problems.
First, when I wanted to redeploy everything, yarn install started hanging in random places, stating that my network is slow (it's not).
As a temporary solution, I decided to run yarn install on the host machine and inside the Dockerfile copy the source with node_modules into the container. It worked, but the second step started failing on the build step:
#23 0.261 yarn run v1.22.22
#23 0.283 $ GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false next build
#23 0.717
#23 0.757   ▲ Next.js 14.2.5
#23 0.757
#23 0.804    Creating an optimized production build ...
#23 13.93 FATAL ERROR: v8::Object::GetCreationContextChecked No creation context available
#23 13.93 ----- Native stack trace -----
#23 13.93
#23 13.93  1: 0xe22fc9 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  2: 0x122b176 v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  3: 0x12405ac v8::Object::GetCreationContextChecked() [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  4: 0xf7d90c  [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  5: 0x7f78dd77613c
#23 13.93
#23 13.93
#23 13.93 #
#23 13.93 # Fatal error in , line 0
#23 13.93 # Missing deoptimization information for OptimizedFrame::Summarize.
#23 13.93 #
#23 13.93 #
#23 13.93 #
#23 13.93 #FailureMessage Object: 0x7fff91793c30
#23 13.93 ----- Native stack trace -----
#23 13.93
#23 13.93  1: 0xffe461  [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  2: 0x28c276b V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  3: 0x139cff3 v8::internal::OptimizedFrame::Summarize(std::vector<v8::internal::FrameSummary, std::allocator<v8::internal::FrameSummary> >*) const [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  4: 0x13a5116  [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.93  5: 0x13a931c v8::internal::Isolate::CaptureDetailedStackTrace(int, v8::StackTrace::StackTraceOptions) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94  6: 0x12361f3 v8::StackTrace::CurrentStackTrace(v8::Isolate*, int, v8::StackTrace::StackTraceOptions) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94  7: 0xf76c96 node::GetCurrentStackTrace(v8::Isolate*, int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94  8: 0xec549b node::DumpJavaScriptBacktrace(_IO_FILE*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94  9: 0xe22fd5 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94 10: 0x122b176 v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94 11: 0x12405ac v8::Object::GetCreationContextChecked() [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94 12: 0xf7d90c  [/usr/local/bin/node]
#23 13.94 13: 0x7f78dd77613c
#23 14.07 Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
#23 14.08 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
#23 14.08 error Command failed with exit code 133.
#23 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c yarn build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 133

When I tried these steps locally on the host machine without Docker, everything was okay. So the problem only occurs inside Docker. I heavily researched the error related to yarn install hanging, and there is a reference that this could be related to slow I/O. The problem with the build also looks like a memory issue.
It seems that Docker, for some reason, doesn't have enough resources or started working slowly. Just a note, we already had a similar issue a few months ago. We tried to completely erase the server, even asked Hetzner to replace our SSDs, but this didn't help and the problem persisted. So we were forced to just move to another server, and it worked okay until now.
I don't believe that for the second time there are some "physical" problems with the server, but it looks very strange.
Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b
NodeJs: 22
Linux: Ubuntu-22.04

I had the same issue pop up today. I tracked down the root cause to the node version 22.5.0 that was introduced recently in the base docker image I was using. Specifying 22.4.0 solved the issue.
Good luck!

Oh my... You just saved me a lot of time. Thank you so much. Also just a reminder that pinning exact version is very important.

Indeed. Saved a lot of time here too.
